# How to obfuscate asp.net application code to avoid unauthorised reverse engineering

Tags: asp.net, obfuscation

How can I obfuscate my asp.net application's code so that if someone gets a chance to copy the entire code they cannot easily read or modify also they should not be able to install (deploy ) it without a key.

Comment: I don't think you can encrypt it and still have it run. What you can do is only deploy compiled code (.dlls) and obfuscate them. That makes it difficult but doesn't prevent reverse engineering.

Comment: Few days before I downloaded free trial of social engine php code. Most of the code files were encrypted and not readable in plain english, I also needed a free trial key to deploy the code which got expired in 14 days, so the trial key cannot be distributed as well. Though the code files were encrypted the web app was executing.

Comment: I think you need to double check what encryption means. Not readable in plain english is not a technical term. It might just mean the code was compiled, or that it was obfuscated. And though you may have needed a code for the site to function for it's intended purpose, that might just be because the code was designed not to work until it had that key, that doesn't mean encryption.

Comment: I had to install ioncube . Is it like ioncube was acting as a decryption engine which was decrypting the code at runtime to execute it ?

Comment: If you look at the product page for Ioncube, you can see it's not doing encryption. It appears it's doing obfuscation and requiring a key for the code to fully function. Exactly as I described above.

Comment: Sir, I understood your point now. Can you help me with some opensource techniques to obfuscate my .net code and some tricks so that the code can only be deployed using a key which will lapse after certain time.